# Android style problems in Eclipse when importing project to another PC

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-styles

Ive been having this issue since a while and I never understood why I had it.Basically, I have an android project,that use a certain theme style, and whenever I want to continue my project on another computer other than the one I created the project on it, I always get 3 errors:

-1 under values, in styles.xml saying :"error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'."

-1 under values-v11, in styles.xml saying: "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'."

-1 under values-v14, in styles.xml saying: "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'."

I do import the external librairies app compat v7 each time on the PC im trying to continue the project on, but those errors stays there.However, I found this could be the problem; right click on project>properties>android under "Library" theres my "..\appcompatv7" but with a red ? beside it(under "Project"); but whenever I click "add",the field of new window that pop up to make me add a new library are all grey and the only option I can choose is Cancel.Even if I delete the actual library.

Does anybody have any clue on how to solve those style errors?

thank you

Comment: Are you using same sdk versions on both PC?

Comment: Do you mean the API? Im using API 16 android 4.1.2 but I think it was on API 20 on the other computer but shouldnt API 20 be compatible with other API?